# Потерял файл ключа .jks. Что можно предпринять?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sha1, google-play-console

При попытке обновить приложение в Play Console

**Загруженный файл APK подписан сертификатом, отличающемся от    указанного вами. Цифровой отпечаток вашего сертификата: 
[ SHA1:    55****************************************** ] , цифровой отпечаток    сертификата электронной подписи APK-файла:
 [ SHA1:    09****************************************** ]**

После переустановки винды потерял этот ключ. 
Написал в тех поддержку пока не отвечают. 
Кто нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой и смог ли восстановить?

Вроде бы в Play Console  есть страничка с подписями. Но там они не .jks 
Что делать народ. Неужели все так плохо ?

Comment: кажется, ты можешь восстановить только из своих бэкапов

Comment: Раньше на Ubuntu сидел.Бекапов нет :(/

Comment: Значить служба поддержки не сможет мне помочь ?

Comment: @dev.emr как можно восстановить закрытый ключ? ответ: никак. нужно было делать его копии и хранить в нескольких местах. Гугл предупреждал, что если ключ будет утерян - обновить приложение будет не возможно.

Comment: А эта новая фишка с сервисом Google Play App Signing, это не кому не помогло?

Comment: а вы какой версией подписывали?